# When I upload an excel file in Django numeric cell format change to General

Tags: django, excel, file-upload

I'm uploading some excel file from a simple HTML form to a Django application, the Excel has two columns one of them with "General Format" and the other one with "Number format". Whenever I upload a file, all the cells change to "General format".

Here some snippet of my code:

```
 <form id="excelFormId" name="excelFormId" 
                  action="/appupload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input required name="excel_file" id="excel_file" type="file"  >
...

 excel_file = request.FILES['excel_file']
 fs = FileSystemStorage(location='../')
 fs.save('myExcel.xls', excel_file)
```

How can I avoid losing the original format?

Comment: Django does not care what your file types are, so this is not something that can happen

Comment: I know, but It has happened. I try saving on disk with FileSystem, xls modules and return directly but the result is the same "Numeric cells change to General"